# Service to dynamically load new content in array in Angular

Tags: angularjs, service

I would like to load external JSON content into my controllers scope. Initiating my scope for the first ten items is no problem. What I want however is to dynamically expand the scope with new items (by scrolling)

For some reason the paging doesnt work in my service when I try to run the loadNews(counter) function. When I log the results of respond of the http get in the service however, the correct data is shown.

When I expand the scopes newsitems, It gets expanded, but only with the first page items.

Here is my little bit of code.

```
app.service('newsService', function ($http, $q) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var deferred2 = $q.defer();
   this.loadNews = function (counter) {
    if (counter == undefined) {
        $http.get('http://domain.com/wp- json/wp/v2/posts').then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    } else {
          console.log(counter); // This returns a correct counter
          $http.get('http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=' + counter).then(function (response) {
          deferred2.resolve(response);
      });
      return deferred2.promise;
    }

  } 
});

app.controller('homeNewsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $cordovaSplashscreen, newsService) {

  $scope.count = 1;

  var promise = newsService.loadNews();
  promise.then(function (response) {
    $scope.newsItems = response.data;
  });

  $scope.loadMore = function (counter) {
    $scope.count += counter;
    var promise = newsService.loadNews($scope.count);
    promise.then(function (response) {
      $scope.newsItems.push.apply($scope.newsItems, response.data);
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle or something

Comment: The code seems pretty straight forward and obvious right? Why is response in $scope.newsItems.push.apply($scope.newsItems, response.data); not the responds from the one in the else statement?

Comment: did you check the array values, are they getting added

Comment: There are objects being added to the $scope.newsItems., but those objects are the same objects as in the get request without the parameter "page". So what I get is an inifinite scroll (works correctly) with infinite added items (also correct), but with the same 10 objects every time the functions loadMore is fired.

Comment: so you only want the new data, or the new data appended to old data?

Comment: On initiating only the first data, on scroll/fire loadMore function I would like to append the new data to the old data

Comment: The problem is not appending data. The problem is the response. The response is always the same. I never get the response from $http.get('http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=' + counter. I only get the response from $http.get('http://domain.com/wp- json/wp/v2/posts')

Comment: got your point now...so is the counter undefined every time you make a request? did you check

Comment: Nope, the counter works. I put a console.log(counter) in my http request and it logs correctly.

Comment: still it is not going to the else part? and if it is going, did you check the response there?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Is deferred.resolve(response); the problem? It has been declarated twice.

Comment: I don't think so, we usually resolve it more than once. Did you log the response here in else...is it correct

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I came up with a factory solution. This worked for me.

```
app.factory('newsItems', function ($http) {
  return {
    getNews: function (counter) {
      if (counter != undefined) {
        return $http({
          url: 'http://www.domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=' + counter,
          method: 'GET'
        })
      } else {
        return $http({
          url: 'http://www.domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
          method: 'GET'
        })
      }
    }
  }
});


$scope.loadMoreNews = function (counter) {
    $scope.count += counter;
    newsItems.getNews($scope.count).then(function (response) {
      $scope.newsItems.push.apply($scope.newsItems, response.data);
    });
};
```